# What does discriminant of polinomial discriminate?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

My understanding of the word when used in other contexts is to mean an object which classifies other objects into classes (possibly based on equivalence relation).  But in what sense is discriminant of a polynomial a classifier?  Or does it mean something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discriminant is closely related to the (possible) number of real roots of the
polynomial. For degree $2$ and $3$, the situation is particularlay easy :

If the discriminant is positive, we have two real roots for degree $2$ and three real roots for degree $3$. If it is negative, we have no real roots for degree $2$ and $1$ real root for degree $3$. If the discriminant is $0$, there is a root with multiplicity greater than $1$.